# Oversized tabs / windows / title in Chrome

Tags: chrome

Just did some system updates, and now Google Chrome is oversized @ 100%. The window, the URL bar, the bookmark bar, everything is scaled to a huge size.

I've been searching around, but still no solution.  Any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm observing the same bug with Chrome stable 43.0.2357.12 on Ubuntu. It looks like a consequence of DPI-related changes in Chrome 43: Chrome [now takes DPI settings into account](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403302), which should be an improvement, except that what it does with these DPI settings seems completely broken.

As a workaround, run

```
google-chrome --force-device-scale-factor=1
```