# Blurry fonts in Google Chrome/Chromium in Linux after switching to a new 27" QHD monitor

Tags: fonts, chrome, resolution

On my previous 1080p monitor 24" fonts in Google Chrome looked great however on my new 27" QHD monitor fonts are extremely blurry.

I've been Googling for a solution for quite some time and I couldn't find anything.

[image: Google Chrome Before]

[image: Google Chrome After]

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250012/unable-to-scale-chrome-on-hdpi-screen-for-arch-linux, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620291/chrome-on-linux-tiny-menus-toolbar-and-default-100-page-size, and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208752/oversized-tabs-windows-title-in-chrome, to tie some more information together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've poked and prodded around and here's what I've found:

1. The issue is not reproducible under `Xnest`.
2. After playing with DPI and choosing a sufficiently low value the issue goes away, however everything else starts looking unnatural, so I cannot change the system-wide DPI value.
3. I've tried to find ways to apply DPI to a single application but nothing has shown up.

I've realized it has something to do with Google Chrome thinking that I have a high DPI display even though I do not.

Luckily, I've discovered an option `--force-device-scale-factor=1` which fixed the issue immediately.