# why the display scaling in fedora 35 is not same as windows. How to make it equal to windows scaling?

Tags: linux, fedora, windows, display, display-settings

**The default display scaling factor in fedora-35 is 1.00.**

[image]

**This is how the chrome websites look with this scaling factor and default 100% zoom**

[image]

**But if you see in windows with default scaling factor of 1.00 and 100% zoom the chrome websites look different.**

[image]

**As far as i know with a scaling factor of 1.00, 1 pixel in css == 1 device pixel.**

- Then why are they different on fedora 35 and windows 11.
- How to make fedora scaling equal to widows scaling because while developing
  websites they are looking very different.
- I am assuming in widows 1 pixel in css == 1 device pixel but not in fedora 35 even
  though the scaling factor is 1.00.
- kindly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blurry fonts in Google Chrome/Chromium in Linux after switching to a new 27" QHD monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645546/blurry-fonts-in-google-chrome-chromium-in-linux-after-switching-to-a-new-27-qhd)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov its hard to understand those articles. It's not just in chrome,all other apps are effected. I would love a good explaination , step by step, easy to understand.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov my question is different. In windows with scaling factor of 1.00 the size of websites ,text,apps is larger than the fedoras with the same scaling factor of 1.00. I want to know why they are different even with same scaling factor and default 100% zoom. How to make fedoras display equal to windows.

Comment: No one seems to get the scaling correct. It's all broken. You also have to look at what the native dpi and what the display driver says it is (`xdpyinfo`). On opensuse, they muck about with that via the xorg config files. Google chrome folk also muck about with it. Then everyone expects either 75 or 96 dpi, which it is rarely is, and when it is above 96, they all do their own thing. Why the heck they couldn't just leave it as native dpi and let everyone handle it themselves, I do not know.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried and it did not work.

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted it. I request to give me some explanation because it is a genuine problem that i am having and i did search a lot for the answer but couldn't find.